# How to import in Java?

Tags: java

So, this is one question my professor asked in the review package she gave us.
Suppose the CLASSPATH is set to ~/2013/tests

currently i'm in directory ~/2013/DEMOS/myClasses and editing the file Subject.java
How to import class Figure in ~/2013/tests/Projects/Final/Figure.java ?

Also, can any of you tell me how exactly CLASSPATH works?

Comment: What research have you done?  Are you using an IDE? It will make doing this much simpler, if you can't work this out.

Comment: importing a class is always relative to src directory.

Comment: Maybe the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) could tell you how it works.

Comment: Quite frankly, the question is stupid. The way you import a class doesn't depend on which directory you're in, and doesn't depend on the CLASSPATH either. You import a class by using its fully qualified name.

Comment: And maybe that was the point of the question?